# Changes to multiple variables within a function in Python 3.x being reset to default values

Tags: python, function

Edit since apparently I wasn't specific enough, despite receiving an answer quickly.

I'm a beginning coder, so please bear with me if this is a painfully obvious/stupid error.

I'm coming into an issue with a project wherein I have starting values that change as they are processed through several different function calls. At a certain point in the program, I print all variables in order to see the changes made. (SPECIFIC PROBLEM OR ERROR>>) This is where I noticed that the variables revert back to their original values, despite being returned. Within the function that changes these variables, I did some testing and can see the variables change, so I'm unsure why the return is not working.

(SPECIFIC ERROR EXAMPLE>>)Here's some example code following my program to show you what I mean:

```
a = 1
b = 1
c = 1
z = 3

def main():
    othercode()

def calculations(a, b, c, z):
    print("a:", a)
    print("b:", b)
    print("c:", c)
    print("z:", z)
    while z > 0:
        check = str(input("Enter a, b, or c: "))
        if check == "a":
            a += 1
            z -= 1
            print("a:", a)
            print("z:", z)
        elif check == "b":
            b += 1
            z -= 1
            print("b:", b)
            print("z:", z)
        elif check == "c":
            c += 1
            z -= 1
            print("c:", c)
            print("z:", z)
        else:
            print("Invalid input.")
    return a, b, c, z

def othercode()
    a, b, c, z = calculations(a, b, c, z)
    print(a, b, c, z)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now, this seems like it should work to me. (DESIRED OUTPUT>>) The output should be an increase in the variables a, b, and c and a corresponding decrease in the resource pool (z variable) depending on the user's inputs. The results I get are the same as those originally defined in main, and my IDE (PyCharm Community) gives me the message (SPECIFIC ERROR MESSAGE>>)`"Statement seems to have no effect..."`

Comment: `print(a, b, c. z)` are you sure?

Comment: what' s the output of the program and what do you expect?

Comment: your `a,b,c,z` are specified inside `main()` - they dont even exists when you call `othercode()` - you are using some other `a,b,c,d` if you do not get any errors - else you somehow circumvent scoping rules. Please post actual code you use.

Comment: Jean-François,
The output should be an increase in the variables a, b, and c and a corresponding decrease in the resource pool (z variable) depending on the user's inputs.

Patrick,
The variables are defined outside of main in my actual program, that's an error on my part when I copied it over. I'll go edit that. My actual program would be ~170 lines because of all the stuff it has fleshed out, so I'm a bit wary about dumping it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just provide all params to your functions, also fixed some other mishaps:

```
def main():
    a,b,c,z = 1,1,1,3 
    othercode(a,b,c,z) # you need to provide those, the local ones here
                       # are not in scope if you call into othercode()

def calculations(a, b, c, z):
    print("a:", a)
    print("b:", b)
    print("c:", c)
    print("z:", z)
    while z > 0:
        check = input("Enter a, b, or c: ")  # removed superflous str w/o ending )
        if check == "a":
            a += 1
            z -= 1
            print("a:", a)
            print("z:", z)
        elif check == "b":
            b += 1
            z -= 1
            print("b:", b)
            print("z:", z)
        elif check == "c":
            c += 1
            z -= 1
            print("c:", c)
            print("z:", z)
        else:
            print("Invalid input.")
    return a, b, c, z

def othercode(aa,bb,cc,zz):    # missing : in this line, also use given params
                               # to avoid scoping problems
    aaa, bbb, ccc, zzz = calculations(aa, bb, cc, zz)
    print(aaa, bbb, ccc, zzz)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Patrick, in your code you have the given parameters duplicated in subsequent calls. I'm just checking to see if I understand this correctly. For a variable that is a word, would the code be like this:

    def othercode(appleapple,ballball,catcat,etcetc):

Sorry to bother you, I'm pretty new and hoping to not make this error again.

Comment: @BrocBaney a variable that is a word? no idea what that means. they are just variable names , I choose different ones in each function so it is easier to see where they came from -  if you use a,b,c,z all over again - you might get sideeffects where an a,b,c-z from global scope bleeds through. You are better of to name them "better" not AA and AAAA and AAAAAAAA but interestrate, interest, years_to_calculate etc. so they have _meaning_

Comment: Right, I use actual names in my programs. The letters were just for ease of reading here. Thank you, that answers what I needed to know. I need to assign them an alias for the duration of their use outside the global scope.

Comment: dont use global scope :D